# RxSwift withLatestFrom weird behavior

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

Today I was migrating my code from ReactiveSwift to RxSwift and came to this weird scenario.

I have an `Observable` composed with `withLatestFrom` operator inside a `ViewModel` class, and it is emitting only on the test subscription I made inside the initializer of the`ViewModel` class at the time of composing it, but not in the subscription I made in the `ViewController`.

The `withLatestFrom` operator from this Observable is accepting another `Observable` that also has been composed with a `withLatestFrom` operator as its parameter.

```
// emit phrases when viewDidLoad emits
let thePhrases = self.viewDidLoadSubject.withLatestFrom(self.configureWithPhrasesSubject)

// This is the problematic Observable
let printThePhrases = self.buttonTappedSubject.withLatestFrom(thePhrases)
```

Here is the code I made to showcase this weird behavior, you can run it in XCode and set the debugger output filter to `[!]` to ignore the garbagge output made by Simulator:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

public final class RxTestViewModel {
    public init() {
        // emit configuredWithPhrases when viewDidLoad emits
        let configPhrases = self.viewDidLoadSubject
            .withLatestFrom(self.configureWithPhrasesSubject)
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0! }

        // Show phrases to be printed on viewDidLoad
        self.toBePrinted = configPhrases.asObservable()

        _ = self.toBePrinted.subscribe(onNext: {
            print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- ViewModel.toBePrinted.onNext -> \($0)")
        })

        // Print first phrase whenever buttonTapped() is called
        self.printSomething = self.buttonTappedSubject
            .withLatestFrom(self.configureWithPhrasesSubject
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0! })

        _ = self.printSomething.subscribe(onNext: {
            print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- ViewModel.printSomething.onNext -> \($0)")
        })
    }

    // MARK: Inputs
    private let configureWithPhrasesSubject = BehaviorSubject<[String]?>(value: nil)
    public func configureWith(phrases: [String]) {
        print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- ViewModel.configureWith")
        self.configureWithPhrasesSubject.on(.next(phrases))
    }

    private let viewDidLoadSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()
    public func viewDidLoad() {
        print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- ViewModel.viewDidLoad")
        self.viewDidLoadSubject.on(.next( () ))
    }

    private let buttonTappedSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()
    public func buttonTapped() {
        print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- ViewModel.buttonTapped")
        self.buttonTappedSubject.on(.next( () ))
    }

    // MARK: Outputs
    public let printSomething: Observable<[String]>
    public let toBePrinted: Observable<[String]>
}

public final class RxTestViewController: UIViewController {

    private let button: UIButton = UIButton()
    private let viewModel: RxTestViewModel = RxTestViewModel()

    public static func instantiate() -> RxTestViewController {
        let vc = RxTestViewController()
            vc.viewModel.configureWith(phrases: ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"])

        return vc
    }
}

extension RxTestViewController {
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupButton()
        self.setupViewModel()

        self.viewModel.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension RxTestViewController {
    private func setupViewModel() {
        _ = self.viewModel.toBePrinted
            .subscribeOn(ConcurrentMainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- RxTestViewController.toBePrinted.onNext -> \($0)")
                self.viewModel.buttonTapped()
            })

        _ = self.viewModel.printSomething
            .subscribeOn(ConcurrentMainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("[!][\(Thread.current)] -- RxTestViewController.printSomething.onNext -> \($0)")
        })
    }
}

extension RxTestViewController {
    private func setupButton() {
        // Add to view
        self.view.addSubview(self.button)

        // Button config
        self.button.setTitle("CLICK ME", for: .normal)
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Auto-layout
        self.button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            self.button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)])
    }

    @objc
    private func buttonTapped() {
        self.viewModel.buttonTapped()
    }
}
```

The expected results should be:

```
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.configureWith
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.viewDidLoad
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.toBePrinted.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- RxTestViewController.toBePrinted.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.buttonTapped
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.printSomething.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- RxTestViewController.printSomething.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
```

But instead I get:

```
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.configureWith
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.viewDidLoad
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.toBePrinted.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- RxTestViewController.toBePrinted.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.buttonTapped
[!][<NSThread: 0x600001fee280>{number = 1, name = main}] -- ViewModel.printSomething.onNext -> ["First phrase", "Second phrase", "Third phrase"]
```

As you can see, the observer subscription is not called at the `ViewController`, only at the `ViewModel`.

Interestingly though, If I call the Observable's `latestFrom` trigger function again (`buttonTapped()`), both the ViewModel subscription and the ViewController subscription gets called as expected.

Also, if I remove the `withLatestFrom` operator from the `configPhrases` observable chain, and add it only to the `toBePrinted` Observable all works as expected.

This makes me think that applying `withLatestFrom` to an Observable that already has applied a `withLatestFrom` operator is bugged out.

Comment: I rather think there might be an issue with threading and not having yet subscribed. Use the `.debug()` operator to find out if the tap happens before you've actually subscribed to `RxTestViewController.printSomething`

Comment: FYI, I copied and pasted your code in a single view and presented your VC from the ViewController and it outputted the "expected results"

Comment: @DanielT. Are you instantiating the controller via it's static instantiate() method?

Comment: @Tylerian Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the behavior you are talking about, possibly because I am presenting the view controller instead of using it in a test harness?

At any rate, keep in mind that when you do `a.withLatestFrom(b)` if `a` emits a value before `b` has emitted any values, then the operator will filter out the emission. Could that be your problem?